# How to set up Mercurial on Snow Leopard with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, mercurial, hgeclipse

I'm using Eclipse with C++ plugins on my macbook, trying some practice projects to improve my skills.  I'd also like to test out Mercurial and get a taste of DVCS.  Unfortunately, Eclipse + Mercurial + OSX seems to be a rare enough combination that there isn't a lot of helpful documentation out there.

What I've done so far:

- Installed Mercurial SCM
- Installed the [HgEclipse](http://www.javaforge.com/project/HGE) plugin
- Installed GnuPG
- Set path to GnuPG and hg executables in Eclipse preferences > Team > Mercurial

I know I can turn a directory into an hg repository by navigating to that directory in terminal and using

```
hg init
```

and then I can add files with

```
hg add
hg commit
```

This should give me an hg repo with my files in it.  So far, so good...but now I begin to falter.

How do I get HgEclipse pointed to my repo?  My synchronize view has a Mercurial option, but when I select it, the Next button is grayed out, and the Finish button doesn't do anything...

Ideally, I would like to set up two local repositories, one personal and one "team" repo, so I can really evaluate Hg as this seems to be the popular configuration.  Does HgEclipse only support commits to a single repo, or can it commit to the local repo *and* push to the "team" repo?

Any other suggestions from DVCS vets on how best to set up my environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To point eclipse at your local repo there are two main ways.

- File -> Import -> Mercurial -> Clone (Starting a new Project from a repo)
- (right click Project) -> Team -> Share Project -> Mercurial

(see [How to turn on Mercurial in existing Eclipse project ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517255/how-to-turn-on-mercurial-in-existing-eclipse-project))

When you are up and running you can Push/Pull to another repository via the Team push/pull menu item.

- (right click Project) -> Team -> Pull ...
- (right click Project) -> Team -> Push ...

Answer (score 0):

Ran through the setup steps again, following [this excellent guide](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/git-mercurial/) and everything is now working.  I had a little trouble getting my brain around the fact that the eclipse workspace is itself a repository.  With that set up, I was able to commit changes and push to another repository very easily.