# How do I enable MercurialEclipse plugin for a project?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I have a project using mercurial for version control, and I'm trying to set it up in Eclipse. I cloned the project from the command line and then opened the project in eclipse by importing it as a maven project.

This works except for that eclipse/MercurialEclipse doesn't seem to pick up that this is an merurial repo.

If I go to project properties, the Mercurial option shows only the message "This project doesn't use MercurialEclipse as a Team provider."

In the "Team Synchronizing" perspective, Synchronize... just gives me a "clone repository wizard" saying "There are no Mercurial resources to syncrhonize".

Does anyone know how to get MercurialEclipse to pick up the existing repository for the project.

Comment: Great stuff asking and answering your own question!

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517255/how-to-turn-on-mercurial-in-existing-eclipse-project

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Figured this out myself.

Right click the project and choose Team > Share project...

That gives a wizard for enabling mercurial integration for the project.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. After creating a project, I then did "Team">"Share" to create a Local Hg repo. However, I cant seem to find how to sync that with a Bitbucket repo. I also get the "This project doesn't use MercurialEclipse as a Team provider." and cant seem to find a way around it. When I go to the "Team Synchronize" perspective, all I get is a blank panel with no options. Help!